# How to call a service with begin and end time as request/input

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, timer, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am looking to call [laser_assembler](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler) call back service -AssembleScans .

```
time begin
time end
---
sensor_msgs/PointCloud cloud
  std_msgs/Header header
    uint32 seq
    time stamp
    string frame_id
  geometry_msgs/Point32[] points
    float32 x
    float32 y
    float32 z
  sensor_msgs/ChannelFloat32[] channels
    string name
    float32[] values
```

I am looking to call this service in my velocity call back function but not how to input choose the start and end time.

There is an example in [laser_assembler](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler) package  using timer call back

```
void timerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent& e)
{
    AssembleScans srv;
    srv.request.begin = e.last_real;
    srv.request.end   = e.current_real;
    client_.call(srv)
}
```

Now I am looking the same service from a velocity call back

```
void  velocity_cb (const geometry_msgs::Twist& cmd_vel)
{
    AssembleScans srv;
    srv.request.begin = ???;
    srv.request.end   = ???;
}
```

Not sure how to input  srv.request.begin , srv.request.end .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285646/how-to-call-a-service-with--begin-and-end-time-as-request/input/) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2018-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know anything about the laser_assembler, but a ros time object can be instantiated like in this example :

```
srv.request.begin = ros::Time::now();
srv.request.end = ros::Time::now() + ros::Duration(59);
```

See [ros time](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time)

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2018-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1